# Ошибка в формате даты (Exception has occurred: CLR/System.FormatException). DateTime, C#

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Есть ли каноническое решения для парсинга даты, которая выходит за границы 24 часов?
Например для таких,

```
'2022.05.22 24:00'
'2022.05.22 24:10'
```

Ошибка, которую я ловлю

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.FormatException
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'The DateTime represented by the string '2022.05.22 24:00' is not supported in calendar 'System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar'.'
```

Строка кода, которая мне это выдает

```cs
...
// values[0]="2022.05.22" и values[1]="24:00"
dateteime = DateTime.Parse((values[0] + ' ' +values[1]), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
```

Понимаю, что могу сделать `Replace` вот так

```cs
...
// values[0]="2022.05.22" и values[1]="24:00"
dateteime = DateTime.Parse((values[0] + ' ' +values[1].Replace("24:", "00:")), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
```

enSO завален подобного рода вопросами, но они либо датируются 10 летней давностью, либо не представляют ценности, так как решают только часть проблемы с датой. А, может, ищу криво.

Comment: `'2022.05.22 24:10'` какой результат для этой даты ожидается? `'2022.05.22 00:10'` или `'2022.05.23 00:10'`?

Comment: @Grundy день плюс один, я это только что допонял... То есть `'2022.05.22 24:10'` по факту должен превратиться в `'2022.05.23 00:10'`. То есть просто replace не достаточно, надо еще и дату обрабатывать, то-то оно мне не  нравится, хотя естевенно, ошибка при замене уходит

Comment: В таком случае можешь парсить отдельно дату и отдельно время в timespan, который просто добавить к дате.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Globalization;
```

```
var values = new string[] { "2022.05.22", "24:10" };

var date = DateTime.Parse(values[0]);

var timeParts = values[1].Split(':');
int hours = int.Parse(timeParts[0]);
int minutes = int.Parse(timeParts[1]);

var dateTime = date.AddHours(hours).AddMinutes(minutes);

Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
```

Как-то так.